# ALTER TABLE item add constraint aa PRIMARY KEY(I_ID) there is error occured said: missing a comma before start a new alter operation(near primary key)

Tags: mysql

```
ALTER TABLE item add constraint aa PRIMARY KEY(I_ID)
```

An error occurred saying:

`missing a comma before start a new alter operation(near primary key)`

Comment: I can execute such a statement with no such error. Are you sure this line is the source of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql we do it like

```
alter table item add primary key (I_ID);
```